# New Mac, installed ruby via rbenv, can't install one gem due to rdoc conflict

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, refinerycms, rbenv

I've recently replaced an aging Mac with a new one, and so I am setting up my new environment. I installed ruby using rbenv, and have installed many gems already, but one, won't seem to install due to this error:

rdoc's executable "rdoc" conflicts with /Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/rdoc
Overwrite the executable? [yN]  N

It's refinerycms of which I've built a production site on and am fairly familiar with. I thought I'd start looking at rbenv first and then look into the actual gem (not much here https://rubygems.org/gems/refinerycms that was of any help, but I'll reach out to their awesome devs next)...I was trying to see what version the refinerycms gem was using.

I appreciate any help!

Thank you, everyone,

Dinos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try prepending `yes |`. This is unlikely to solve the problem but you might also wanna take a look at this issue on github where people are trying to solve the same problem: 
[Conflict when installing gems that have default versions](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/405)

Comment: Thank you, George! You're right, that didn't solve it, but thank you for the link to Github...I'll head on over there and review.